# Attempt to read property "id" on bool in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, loops

I got this data from an external API call.

```
$countries = @file_get_contents('https://external../api/countries'); 
$countriesArray = json_decode($countries, true);
print_r($countriesArray); 
//dd($countriesArray);
```

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [message] => countries
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Afghanistan
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Åland Islands
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Albania
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => Algeria
                ) 
                ....
```

When try the dd
`dd($countriesArray)`result is ok

[image]

When try to display the result in loop, I got this error

**Attempt to read property "id" on bool**

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
    @foreach($countriesArray as $key => $country)
        <option
            value="{{$country->id}}" {{ old('country_id', $user->country_id) == $country->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
            @lang($country->name)
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your result, `data` key `$countriesArray` contains data in array format.

```
@if(!empty($countriesArray['data']))
    @foreach($countriesArray['data'] as $key => $country)
            <option
                value="{{$country['id']}}" {{ old('country_id', $user->country_id) == $country['id'] ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                @lang($country['name'])
            </option>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

seems like you are treating the elements of the $countriesArray as objects, but they are actually arrays.
try access the elements using square brackets

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
    @foreach($countriesArray as $key => $country)
        <option
            value="{{ $country['id'] }}" {{ old('country_id', $user->country_id) == $country['id'] ? 'selected' : '' }}>
            @lang($country['name'])
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: still no good. got this error `Trying to access array offset on value of type bool `

Comment: @Drunken M, can you try to get data from `$countriesArray['data']`. I have posted my answer.